# Jasmine mock failed with `apply` but ok with normal function call

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6

Why do I can't assert jasmine spy when the implementation is using `apply` instead of normal function call? The solution is not to use `apply`, but it is prone to error if signature of the third party method being spied upon have changed.

The following code example is simplified for demonstration purposes only and is written using ES6 syntax.

With the following test:

```
describe("foo", function(){}
  it("calls bar", function(){
    spyOn(thirdparty, "bar");

    foobar.foo("foo", "bar");

    expect(thirdparty.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith("foo", "bar");
  });
);
```

The following code failed:

```
foo(){
  thirdparty.bar.apply(arguments);
}
```

But the following code passed:

```
foo(foo, bar){
  thirdparty.bar(foo, bar);
}
```

The above solution is prone to error if for example the implementation of `bar` changed from this:

```
bar(foo, bar){
  // NOOP
}
```

To something like this:

```
bar(foo, options = { bar: 'bar' }) {
  // NOOP
}
```

Anyone care to share some insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.apply()` [takes an additional, first, argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which indicates what the `this` object should be inside the function that gets called. You're not passing that argument.

Try this:

```
thirdparty.bar.apply(thirdparty, arguments);
```

However, given that you set [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), you can also use this:

```
foo() {
  thirdparty.bar(...arguments);
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply).

Comment: OMG, I forgot that `this` context on the first argument. Thanks! Also nice tips for the spread operator.